# Javascript - Accessing node.js application remotely

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows-server-2003

I am running nodejs application on my windows server 2003 with the below link and it works fine:

`http://localhost:3000`

Now I want to access this application remotely from any other computer (not just over lan). So i added 3000 to be allowed port in the server firewall (both TCP and UDP). But i cannot access this remotely from other systems for example with the following link:

`http://server-ip-address:3000`

I have self hosted it. I also have it to listen to all interfaces:

`server.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');`

In the browser i am getting the following error in the console:
`GET http://server-ip-address:3000 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Am I missing something? Is there any other stuffs to be configured to access my application remotely?

Comment: is there a router between the server and the internet connection? If so, have you forwarded the traffic on port 3000 to your server?

Comment: @Neutrosider no there is no router between server and internet connection...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)?

Just download it, unzip it, and run it from the command line with something like this:

`ngrok http 3000`

It will display a console with information including a link you can use to access localhost port 3000 remotely.

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)

Tunnel Status                 online
Version                       2.0.19/2.0.20
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040
Forwarding                    http://16d9ve53.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
Forwarding                    https://16dvbe53.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90
                              0       6       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

HTTP Requests
-------------

GET /favicon.ico                                                 404 Not Found
GET /docs/css/vendor/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff 200 OK
GET /docs/js/docs.js                                             200 OK
GET /docs/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js                             200 OK
GET /docs/css/docs.css                                           200 OK
GET /docs/js/vendor/jquery.min.js                                200 OK
GET /docs/css/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css       200 OK
GET /docs/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css                           200 OK
GET /docs                                                        200 OK
GET /                                                            302 Moved Temporarily
```